# docker-compose how to pass all env vars from .env file to container without explicitly defining them in compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Say I have hundreds of env vars defined in `.env` file

```
ENV1=blah
...
ENV100=foo
```

Is there a way so that docker-compose doesn't require me to define them again in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

eg.

```yaml
services:
  my_app:
    restart: always
    image: some_image
    hostname: my_app
    environment:
      - pass all from .env
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my colleague, I missed the section that I can point to an `.env` file within a service

```
services:
  my_app:
    restart: always
    image: some_image
    hostname: my_app
    env_file:
      - ../.env
```